# On Git Bash, I get an error `cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory` whenever I run the cd command

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, git-bash, cd

I've been trying to find out by this problem is happening, I'm using Windows 10 and this error occurs on Git Bash.

Whenever I run the cd command to change the directory, I get the following error:

`cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`

However, the cd command still works, as it changes the directory, but this message appears below the command every single time, and I'm not sure why, and I can't find anything related to this problem online, specially with Windows 10.

I have a Ubuntu WSL, and when I use it to access `/dev/fd/` I can see several numbers, but 63 is not present, and `touch /dev/fd/63` does not work.

This started happening recently, I believe right when I tried installing RVM on my machine, and followed this instructions: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

And I ran this command on Git Bash

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`

The install seems to have worked, however that message has been popping up everytime on `cd`, only on Git Bash, and not on Ubuntu WSL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Simply ran `rvm implode --force` to remove rvm, then removed all references to rvm on my .bashrc, .profile, etc. files on my user folder.